# SQL Average Count of records over n months

Tags: ms-access-2007

I'm trying to do something that seems simple but I can't figure out how to write it up in SQL. I have a table of records including a field containing a date. I would like to get an overall average number of records per month using that date field. This is not an AVG that is grouped by month, but an overall average.

So if my table contains quotes, and there is 7 different months of data in that table, I'm looking to get:

`Total number of records / n months of data`

Now I need to get this into SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use the `DateDiff` function on the `Min` and `Max` of your date field.

[DateDiff function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/datediff-function-HA001228811.aspx):

```
DateDiff ( interval, date1, date2, [firstdayofweek], [firstweekofyear])
```

Example:

```
SELECT count(*) / DateDiff('m', Min(date), Max(date))
FROM ...
```

How does this work?

`count` will give you the total number of rows (# of quotes in your quotes table), and `DateDiff` will give you the total number of months between the first and last date.